# Concatenate variables + new line in PHP

Tags: php, variables, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a php new line with variables, and, searching in Stack Overflow I found the vai to concatenate variables and put new line, so I have done this:

```
 $mail->Body = "<br />".$message."<br />"." - ".$email." -".$name;
```

But the email arrive like this:

```
<br />MessageOftheperson<br /> - example@gmail.com -NameOfThePerson
```

I would like it to be:

```
MessageOfThePerson
example@gmail.com -NameOfThePerson
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So I guess its not a HTML email. Use `"\n"` or `PHP_EOL`

Comment: it works this way!! Many thanks!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly do you know how can i let it bold?

Comment: Sorry no. Not in a plain text email

Comment: Okay! thanks anyway! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've written will do a newline in HTML.

You can use "\n".

Comment: Do you know how i can let in bold too?

Answer (score 0):

Always set content-type when sending HTML email

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: sorry, i dont understand why to do that, just \n solved, is not  "charset" for setting up the Accentuation? tx even so :)